# what is mean of error LNK unresolved external symbol?

Tags: linker-errors

anyone can help me to undrestand this linker error?
how i can found exact place of error from reading this linker error?

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) const Serialization::Serialization::IBufferWriter::`vftable'" (__imp_??_7IBufferWriter@Serialization@1@6B@) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Serialization::Serialization::IBufferWriter::IBufferWriter(class Utils::IBuffer &)" (??0IBufferWriter@Serialization@1@QAE@AAVIBuffer@Utils@@@Z)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you are making a DLL via Visual Studio.
Change `__declspec(dllimport)` to `__declspec(dllexport)` will fix it.
If you define it via macro definition, modify it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It means you're missing dependencies. Assuming Visual Studio, right click on your project file -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies -> add the .lib file you need. Make sure to do it for both the Debug and Release builds.

When you're using some library, first you need to include the necessary header files so the compiler works, and then you need to add the necessary .lib files so the linker works.

Comment: problem here that i link required library in the console program